# How can I connect Tablet to android SDK in Eclipse

Tags: java, android

I an developing an application in android and I want to connect tablet to Android Eclipse so that I can use Tablet instead of AVD.Is it possible to do that? If yes how can I do it?

I have Eclipse with android SDK 15 i.e. android 4.0.3 and Tablet with OS Android 4.0.3.

Comment: have you got solution? i too need to connect tablet to android SDK in Eclipse.. If you get please post solution.

Comment: No,I am steel searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem. Two notes:

- For some devices you need to install appropriate drivers, and they may usually be found in the vendor's site.
- You need to enable the devices for debugging, [take a look here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up).

Answer (score 0):

install the drivers for your tablet or the one from google..enable usb debugging mode in you settings>development>enble usb debugging

your ready to go..just debug your code and it will run on the tablet

Comment: it connected but while starting for development it asking Android driver is missing. what shall i do??

Comment: seems the drivers aren't installed well... "$adb devices" command should detect every android device that is connected..u can do that by entering into platform folder of sdk from cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue , 
Actually my laptop is too slow to use emulator so i decided to debug on tab.
steps i follow

1) Let eclipse have usb debugging software
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

2) get and install the driver for my windows 7 os, from asus as I am using fonepad 7. from here 
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

3) Turn usb debugging in android, you will find out in google how to do that. Need to tap on build version several times will turn it on. Then enable usb debugging

HW/SW list I am using 
a) Windows 7 
b) Asus fonepad 7 android 4.4.2

Key is you need to find correct driver for your android device.